# Trying to make a formula to find maximum driving time.

Tags: problem-solving

I am trying to figure out how to make a formula (that will eventually be used in excel.) to figure out, how much driving time could be done in a block of time. In this case, 24 hours.

And theses are the variables: 1 Driver can drive 3 different cars, each car has a cool down period that it must rest before before being driven again. (CoolX, CoolY, CoolZ). Now the driver can drive each of these cars at a track to get a track time. (TrackX, TrackY, TrackZ).

I've made a way which kinda get to what I want, but I don't think is quite right and is a bit convoluted. (TrackX~Z, CoolX~Z are Minutes in decimal form due to how excel stores the info)

```
TrackX + CoolX = CycleX
TrackY + CoolY = CycleY
TrackZ + CoolZ = CycleZ
```

Then I use the car with the highest Cycle [of X, Y, and Z] (MaxCycle)

```
1 / MaxCycle * (TrackX + TrackY + TrackZ) * 24 = MaxDriveTime
```

The 1 is for 1 Day, and 24 is for 24 hours, given that of Excel's Time info. And now that I'm writing it down this way, I realize the answer I getting so far from excel is not right (Though is close to what I have in my head to what I thought would be the right answer.)

Comment: Do you expect/want the driver to drive all three cars in a day ? or only one ? and does he drive a single car several times ?

Comment: He'd be driving all three cars in a day, as soon as its finished coming off the cooldown period. So once he drove the 1st car for X amount of time, which would then take X amount time to cooldown, then drive the 2nd car, then 3rd car, then back to the 1st once it is off the cooldown period, then the 2nd car once its off the cooldown, then 3rd, repeating the process. And would continue for a period of 24 hours.

Comment: OK, I understand how you got the formula. Do you assume that the cool-down times are much greater than the track times ?

Comment: Yes, Track times are going to be 5mins~30mins, while cool-down times can run up 30mins~6 hours. (Shorter track times/Shorter Cool-down, Longer track times/Longer Cool-down)